# AS3 - How to put all instances in one code for hit testing?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have 2.5D game so I cannot put all collision objects in a movieclip container, because I need to keep them as separate display objects. I have multiple instances in the stage. I wouldn't want to go write all the hitTest code for all the objects:

```
if (player.hitTestObject(object1)
if (player.hitTestObject(object2)
if (player.hitTestObject(object2)... etc
```

So I would like to know how to `hitTest` all these instances in one code. I have them added on the stage with instance names, so they are not variables and not added by using the `addChild` code.

Comment: are all the objects instances of the same library object?

Comment: No they are different objects.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of ways to make it less tedious.  I'll show a few:

1. Make a container.  You could make a container movie clip and put all the objects in that. Those objects are still individual objects after that (as per your reason in your question for not wanting to go this route). Then you can iterate over all the children of that movie clip:

   ```
   var i:int = container.numChildren;

   while(i--){
       if(player.hitTestObject(container.getChildAt(i) as DisplayObject)){
           //hit,  do something
       }
   }
   ```
2. Put all the objects in an array, then iterate over that array:

   ```
   //when you app starts:

   var objectArray:Array = [object1,object2,object3]//etc.

   //OR, if you have say object1 - object20, you could do something like this:

   //vector is basically the same as an array except every item has to be of the same type (on inherit from it)
   var objectArray:Vector.<DisplayObject> = new Vector.<DisplayObject>();
   for(var i:int=1;i<=20;i++){
       var obj:DisplayObject = this.getChildByName("object" + i) as DisplayObject;
       if(obj) objectArray.push(obj);
   }

   //THEN, later, when you do your hit test:

   var i:int = objectArray.length;
   while(i--){
       if(player.hitTestObject(objectArray[i])){

       }
   }
   ```

Comment: 3. Use both 1&2: place all object in a container and use `numchildren` + `getChildAt()` to get them into an array. This has two advantages: 1) you don't have to give any instance names manually, which is prone to error 2) you can access the object via array, which is usually faster than display list methods and also more flexible